# Android AlertDialog Builder Issue with image

Tags: android, builder, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make a application where a dialog will come from where user will be able to choose an option...
I want the alert dialog like this,,,
An image with the corresponding text

Here is the sample image I am looking ..
http://garr.me/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/sharevia.jpg

I also want to change the "share picture via" text.

Thanks in advance
Tanmay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer to this question: [android image inside single select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211927/android-image-inside-single-select/3281239#3281239)