# AlertDialog with SimpleAdapter and single choice mode does not show item clicked

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-adapter

I need to show an `AlertDialog` with a few custom rows. These rows should have a radio button on the right, and the choice mode should be single mode (hence radio buttons).

What I have:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> it = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("asd", "test1");
it.add(map);
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("asd", "test2");
it.add(map);
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("asd", "test3");
it.add(map);

SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(context, it, R.layout.dialog_row, new String[] { "asd" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(sa, -1, null);
// here are added positive and negative buttons
builder.show();
```

xml for `dialog_row`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/rh_3" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `AlertDialog` shows up as I expect - but when I click an item, the radio button remains unchecked. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3281239/554002

Basically I had to make a custom `ArrayAdapter` and just use a `CheckedTextView` as the only element in my layout xml instead of the elements posted above.